# Recursively Search on a Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

can anybody help me to trace this piece of code if its correct or incorrect.i am studying recursion these days.

```
boolean search(Element element) {
    Element c=first;
    if(c==null)
        return false;
    else if(element.asset < c.asset)
        if(c.left==null)
            return false;
        else
            return search(c.left);
    else if(element.data>c.data)
        if(c.right==null)
            return false;
        else
            return search(c.right);
     else  
         return element.asset==c.asset;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it?  What happens?

Comment: What can we say : syntactically speaking, it's correct java. Does it fit what you wanna do ? It should but the real test, as most of the time, is running it as pointed @Oli Chalesworth.

Regards, Stéphane

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you put braces `{}` around all your `if`s. I have no idea if those if-else-ifs are actually nesting as you intend them to.

Comment: I believe the else-if's are fine, however, the final `else` is unnecessary. This looks like a proper traversal algorithm (again, you should run an explore behavior - I'm just glancing at it) for an `ordered` binary search tree and it would certainly (again, provided it runs properly) work for an AVL tree.

Answer (score 3):

it lacks stop condition. you should check if t.left == null, or you will get NullPointerException. also, you should return `t.left.isExist(..)` OR `t.right.isExist(...)` and not isExist [you will want to invoke this method on the son]

currently, this version will get into infinite loop - because you will always check in the same root node.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't symmetric.

for one side, you call `isExist(t.left)`, for another you call `isExist(a.right)`

You probably want to call `t.left.isExist(a)` and `t.right.isExist(a)`, but that is purely speculative as you do not have a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for us to look at.

Comment: @denis, A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/): a short, self contained, correct example.  If root is really this, then your code *might* be correct.  If root is the root of the tree, you will never progress beyond one layer deep.  Try formulating a SSCCE, then ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

It is syntactically correct Java.  But I don't see how it could possibly be doing what you intend.

It appears that the 'element' parameter is the thing you are searching for and the 'first' field in the current class is the root of the binary tree.

It's unclear if the key for the binary tree and search (in the Element class) is 'asset' or 'data'.  The 'less than' test uses 'asset', while the 'greater than' test uses 'data'.  It seems likely that both lines should use the same field.  It might be that one of these two fields ('asset' or 'data') should **not** be referenced in this method at all.  Maybe the last line of the method should be just 'return true;'?

*(I suspect that the "stop condition" and the "code isn't symmetric" answers above are both incorrect.  But I could be wrong:  It's hard to tell with only the code given.)*

I agree that infinite looping is likely:  I suspect that you need to create a second 'search' function that accepts two 'Element' parameters -- one being the thing to search for (like the current 'element' parameter) and the other being the next Element to search -- the equivalent of current local variable 'c'.  I would do the "Extract Method" refactoring on everything in the body of the current 'search' method except the first line, and then change the two recursive calls to use the new method.

*(Some of this is speculative, based on me guessing what you want or intend, given limited information.  So I could, of course, be quite wrong.)*